# I have created a form, but posts are not coming

Tags: php, post

I have created a form, but posts are not coming. Form Code

```
<form method="post" action="contact.php">
        <form class="quote">
                    <div>
                        <label>Name</label><br>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Name">
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label>Email</label><br>
                        <input type="email" placeholder="Emial Address">
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label>Message</label><br>
                        <textarea placeholder="Message"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <button class="button_1" type="submit">Send</button>
                </form>
```

contact.php code

```
<?php $to = 'demo@spondonit.com'; $firstname = $_POST["fname"]; $email= $_POST["email"]; $text= $_POST["message"]; $headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "rn"; $headers .= "From: " . $email . "rn"; $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "rn"; $message ='<table style="width:100%"> <tr> <td>'.$firstname.' '.$laststname.'</td> </tr> <tr><td>Email: '.$email.'</td></tr> <tr><td>Email: '.$text.'</td></tr> </table>'; if (@mail($to, $email, $message, $headers)) { echo 'The message has been sent.'; }else{ echo 'failed'; } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the route of the page is wrong, try:

```
action="/contact.php">
```

if it's on the same folder

Answer (score 0):

You really need to provide more  detail - what does it mean that posts are not coming? Do you see the "failed" message or nothing at all?

But, most importantly: you use identifiers such as `$_POST['fname']` but there is nothing in your HTML indicating that a text input value should be sent as "fname". You need to add a [name](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#Attributes) attribute to all of your `<input>`s, for example:

```
<input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="Name">
```

Neither `placeholder=` or `<label>` suffice - they only affect how the form is displayed on the webpage and not how it is sent to the server.